# How do I ignore CVS directories with Git?

Tags: git

How to I configure .gitignore to ignore all CVS subdirectories? Do I need a .gitignore in every directory or can I just place one in the root?

Comment: What's wrong with just deleting all the CVS directories! :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One in the root will be fine, containing:

```
CVS/
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a trailing slash? I.e. CVS/

Comment: Good that's what I had. Just wasn't sure if it would work. Will test it out now. Thanks!

Comment: With a trailing slash, it will only match directories.  Without a trailing slash, it will also match files and symbolic links.